# MongoDB Mongoose - improve performance by mirroring a field from another collection/document

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose

I have some performance issues with a read query in mongoose.

**Problem:**
I read a list of documents from a collection, let's say A (~1k elements). Then for each of them I need to find another related document in a different collection (let's call it B), from which a take a couple of fields to be returned on the query. This makes the query pretty big.

**Solution (I have in mind):**
Of course I could have the fields I need from B into A and each time I update B I'll also update A. Classic tradeoff in no-sql dbs. What I'm wondering is: isn't there something moongose provides to have this automatic? Some think field A.X mirrors field B.X, so each update in field B.X would also update that in field A.X, but having A.X readlony.

Does it make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of performance issue's you currently have?, Is it really such a bottleneck to lookup on 1k documents?, unfortunately no such feature exists in `mongo` or `mongoose` you will have to implement custom logic yourself to achieve your solution

Comment: It takes seconds. I need the query to fish up in less than one and that can only happen if i query just 1 collection instead of having 1 x n of documents in collection A x 2 queries